# MySQL Query sort by DESC when 2 fields match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

Logic:

1) When id & id1 match, I want to sort DESC (eg. id=9 is highest score=400, id=1 is 2nd highest score=150)

2) Below the matching row I want all id1's that are the same as the match sorted by id ASC (eg. id=10 & id1=9 will be directly below the id=9 & id1=9 row)

**Note: id is unique and auto incremented

Original data:

```
id  id1 score
1   1   150
2   1   70
3   3   80
4   3   250
5   3   800
6   3   560
7   7   100
8   7   195
9   9   400
10  9   35
```

Desired output:

```
id  id1 score
9   9   400
10  9   35
1   1   150
2   1   70
7   7   100
8   7   195
3   3   80
4   3   250
5   3   800
6   3   560
```

Comment: MySQL does not offer the ability to change *how* you are sorting from one row to another. It will apply the `ORDER BY`(sorting) to all rows returned by a query

Comment: btw it would help if you named the tables involved i.e. where is `id` from vs `id1`? and `score`?

Comment: This is all in one table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your query:

```
select
    t1.id,
    t1.id1,
    t1.score
from
    myTable t1
    left join myTable t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id and t2.id = t2.id1
order by
    t2.score desc,
    t1.id=t1.id1 desc,
    t1.id asc
```

**[sql-fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca298/4/0)**

Comment: Hi, the output I included is correct. It is filtered by score then id

Comment: @Bzyzz Ah, I understand now, I thought you wanted to filter by score desc when matching and score asc in other cases. I fixed it now to what you want by changing `score` into `id` in the last line.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Yours works great. I've also accomplished the desired output through TWO scripts.  The FIRST one looks for all rows with id=id1 and sorts DESC. The SECOND gets all rows where id1 equals the one from the FIRST script. So... after I get the first row of data, I run a while loop to populate the 2nd script